# How to call a method on View layer from Controller layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms

Sorry if this is a supid question. I have acquainted with c # for 2 months.
I have created a winform app, which is designed follow by MVC pattern. Now, I get a problem: I want to call a method on View, from Controller layer.

On View layer, I wanto show Login form when ShowLoginForm() is called.

On controller layer, I have a timer control. I set schedule time to import my data to DB automatically. because my data is downloaded from my server, I need declare username\password via Login form on View.

```
private void ImportToDB()
    {            
        if (myControllerObject.GetServerConnection() == null)
        {
            //call ShowLoginForm() on View
        }
        //my code which i want to do
    }
```

How do I do to solve this problem? Could you suggest me some technical (I thought delegate, callback)?

Comment: Emm ... you cannot "call methods" on a layer. Are you sure that you know what a layer is? Because to me it looks like you are just replacing words "instance"  with "layer".

Answer (score 0):

As per the MVC pattern:

- The controller builds a model
- The view is rendered based on the aforementioned model

The easiest solution I can think of is adding a dedicated `bool ShowLoginForm` property in the model.